# NGINX Reverse Proxy WSS to Amazon API Gateaway

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, aws-api-gateway, nginx-reverse-proxy

Im trying to set up a reverse wss proxy with nginx to an amazon api gateaway websocket api but I have had no luck with the configuration of nginx so i would be glad if you helped me sort this out.

Let me give you some details:

I have an EC2 instance running nginx that has attached to it an elastic ip address.

I also have dns records to point traffic from connect.example.com to that ip address.

I have set up nginx as a reverse proxy to proxy the traffic from connect.example.com to app.example.com on port 443 with ssl(I have generated the relevant certificates).

On app.example.com lies a websockets api on amazon's api gateaway service.

I can see from nginx's access logs that my requests reach the ec2 instance but I always get error responses no matter how i change the nginx config file(400,403,500,502 etc).

I dont seem to understand where the problem lies even though I have searched around and tried various configurations.

Im attaching my config files below for reference:

nginx.conf

```html
# Based on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#nginx-conf
user               daemon daemon;

worker_processes  auto;
error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";
pid               "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/nginx.pid";

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    #include       mime.types;
    #default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format    main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log    "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";
    #add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path      "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;
    #connection_pool_size 112;
    #sendfile           on;
    #tcp_nopush         on;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;
    #gzip               on;
    #gzip_http_version  1.0;
    #gzip_comp_level    2;
    #gzip_proxied       any;
    #gzip_types         text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;
    #ssl_protocols      TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    #ssl_ciphers        HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    client_max_body_size 80M;
    #server_tokens on;

    #include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

    # HTTP Server
    #server {
        # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
    #    listen  80;

    #    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";
#       include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/ssl/ssl-redirect.conf";
#        location /status {
#            stub_status on;
#            access_log   off;
#            allow 127.0.0.1;
#            deny all;
#        }
#    }


    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/ssl/ssl.conf";


}
```

ssl.conf

```html
resolver app.example.com;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    #listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name connect.example.com;
    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt;

    ssl_certificate_key /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;



underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Key $http_sec_websocket_key;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass https://ws-backend$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_read_timeout 9000;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        #Websocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Protocol $http_sec_websocket_protocol;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Extensions $http_sec_websocket_extensions;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Version $http_sec_websocket_version;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Accept $http_sec_websocket_accept;

    }





    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location = /404.html {

    }





    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {

    }



}

 upstream ws-backend {
        server app.example.com:443;
}
```

When i connect directly to app.example.com i have no problem and the response is the following:

[expected response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCktF.jpg)

But when i connect though connect.example.com i get the following response:

[actual response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWUEA.jpg)

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue? i'm facing the same issue here 403

Comment: No I have had no luck. I ended up coding the "proxy" my self with python and fast api. But If you have any suggestions feel free to share.

Comment: You can find the code of the above mentioned reverse proxy in the following repo.
https://github.com/flokos/fast-api-websockets-reverse-proxy